# Error Notice: Undefined index: rate in C Bd mysql Php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Lo que pasa es tengo una variable en javascript llamada rate, y al guardar dicha variable en la BD me sale un error, no se a que se deba este error o ¿como guardaría una variable (arreglo) de javascript en Php?. SIN AJAX.

Aquí esta el código:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="es">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">    

</head>

 <body>

 <div class="container">

    <form name = "form1" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" autocomplete ="off">
    <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
        <label for="comentario">Comentario :</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="comentario" name = "comentario">            
    </div>   
    <label for="comentario">Calificacion :</label>      
    <div class='starrr' id='rating-student' name = "rating-student">         </div>     <br>
    <input type="submit" name = "enviar" id="enviar" class="btn btn-success" value="Calificar">
    <div class="msg"></div>
</div>  
 </form>
  <hr>

  <?php
                     require 'conexion.php';
                            if(!empty($_POST)){

                            $comentario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['comentario']);
                            $rating = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['rate']);


                            $sql = "INSERT INTO comentarios (comentario, rating) VALUES ('$comentario', '$rating')";
                            $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
                            if($resultado){
                            echo "Registro insertado";      
                        }else{
                            echo "No se pudo insertar el registro";
                            }
                        }


            ?>

   <script src="js/estrellita.js"></script>

  <script>
    // rating
   var rate;
  $('#rating-student').starrr({
   change: function(e, value){ 
    rate = value;          
     if (value) {
      $('.your-choice-was').show();      
     } else {
      $('.your-choice-was').hide();
    }
   }
  });
  </script>

   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Sin ajax no puedes guardar variables js en la bd, ya que estás se quedan del lado del cliente, necesitas forzosamente hacer un submit o algo para enviarla al servidor, si solo no quieres usar ajax, puedes usar fetc() que es una variante

Comment: Siempre que digas, me sale un error, escribe cual es el error. Nosotros no sabemos que error te da, y capaz el error da una pista de tu problema y su solución.

Comment: @Sr1871 así es antes tenia un ajax para hacer el guardado de datos pero ahora quiero hacerlo un submit.

Comment: @gbianchi El error que me da es: Notice: Undefined index: rate in C, no se pudo insertar el registro.

Comment: Igual el error que te da, nada que ver con ajax o no ajax, hay un indice en algun lado que te falta

Comment: Una cosa es el script JS que corre en el navegador, otra diferente el script PHP interpretado por el servidor. Te sugiero leer al respecto para entender por qué una variable en el script no está disponible para PHP